# As3 Naming dynamically created instances

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

still fairly new to to as3, but I'm trying to name a instance of my player movieclip, so that i can remove it later on.

this is how im adding and removing. These functions get called when the packet is sent to the client from the server.

```
public static function addPlayer(userName:String, intX:int, intY:int):void
{
    var player:Player = new Player();
    player.name = userName;
    player.username.text = userName;
    player.x = intX;
    player.y = intY;
    Main.stage1.addChild(player);
    trace(Main.stage1.getChildByName(userName).name);
    var index:int = Main.stage1.getChildIndex(player);
    trace(index);
}

public static function removePlayer(userName:String):void
{
  //Var o:DisplayObject = Main.stage1.getChildByName(userName);//nulls?
    var o:DisplayObject = Main.stage1.getChildByName("CrystalLynn");//works?
    Main.stage1.removeChild(o);
}
```

I've traced userName when its passed, and it comes out CrystalLynn, which is the name of my second player, but when I use that passed variable it ends up being null, but if I implicitly tell it that the instance name its looking for is "CrystalLynn" it finds it, any idea why this is?

Comment: Are you sure about that server works correctly and you are receiving correct `userName` for removing?

Comment: add `trace(userName);` into removePlayer, and check what you are passing :)

Comment: Yea I'm positive its passing the correct name, already traced it.

Comment: After some testing you can say you pointed me in the right direction, I found that the server since its using netty when writing a string it's adding an escape char to every packet, so username had an escape char on the end of it somehow, it wasn't being stripped off but it wasn't showing when traced, it took adding a second string to the trace to see it was on a new line.